# SWIFT: label output with multiline breaks from an array

Tags: arrays, swift, label, output, multiline

I am trying to print out best scores on to a label from an array. There are top 10 scores in an (NSUserDefault) array, and these scores need to be displayed in a label with highest score on top and lowest score at the bottom.

I am having hard time separating the lines from each rank.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post relevant code that demonstrates your problem. Right now - nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line break using `\n`.

In the Interface Builder set the number of row's of the label to 0.
or just do it programatically :

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

Tell me what are the results :)

Answer (score 0):

You could First sort the array in descending order.  After that you can try the following code :

```
//Assuming your array is called arr and Label is called label
for var i=0;i<10;i++{
   label.text=label.text+"\n\(arr[i])"
}
```